# Freeze account for a limited time after transaction

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation

Is it possible ina contract to freeze an account for a specific period of time, 1 month in example, after a transaction, let say the user sends 1 ETH to my contract and he can't do another transaction for a month?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the account from doing *any* transactions, but you can prevent interactions with your contract. E.g. the following should only allow a contract to send ether to the contract if it's been at least 30 days since the account's last transfer. (This code is completely untested.)

```
contract Freezing {
    mapping(address => uint256) lastDeposit;

    function deposit() public payable {
        require(lastDeposit[msg.sender] + 30 days < now);

        lastDeposit[msg.sender] = now;
    }
}
```